# Problems with Extjs.getBody

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have this line of code

```
 var width_client = Ext.getBody().getWidth(true);
```

and I get that Ext.getBody() is null.
I asume that this check is doen before Ext.getBody() becames not null, but dont' know were or what to change.

Any idea how to solve this?

I use extjs 4.0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access document.body when it is rendered. From your question I made a conclusion that your code was located inside `<head>`. When this code is executed there is no `<body>` rendered yet. You have to wrap your code by a function and pass this function to [Ext.onReady](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-onReady) (or [Ext.onDocumentReady](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-onDocumentReady)) method:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    alert(Ext.getBody().getWidth(true));
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ArkUZ/).

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait until the page is loaded and ready.
Try this.

```
Ext.onReady(function() { Ext.getBody().getWidth();})
```